# My phone just notified me that Kickback and Soundback were updated, what are they?

Tags: updates

My Motorola Droid just informed me that Kickback and Soundback were updated. Clicking on the updates takes me nowhere, and they aren't listed in installed programs that I can see. What are these programs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are accessibility apps. [One of Motorola's FAQ questions](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/39900/~/droid---hearing-aid-compatibility) summarizes their purposes well:

> **KickBack** - Check to vibrate the phone briefly as feedback as you navigate the phone’s user interface, press buttons, and so on.
>
> **TalkBack** - Check to cause an installed speech synthesizer to speak the labels or names of items as you navigate the phone’s user interface.
>
> **SoundBack** - Check to play a sound as you navigate the phone’s user interface.

Comment: Makes me rest a bit easier knowing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Kickback / Soundback / talkback are Google's accessibility offerings. To turn them on, go to SETTINGS > ACCESSIBILITY.

They allow users with low vision to navigate around Android by reading out and giving noises / vibrating feedback when buttons are pressed or new notifications are shown.